# transit to next page from casGenericSuccess page using link in jasing cas single sign on

Tags: spring-webflow, single-sign-on, cas, spring-webflow-2, jasig

I want to navigate to my added jsp page from casGenericSuccess.jsp but I am not able to transit to next page using hyperlink.

What i did is:

changes in login-webflow.xml

```
    <view-state id="viewGenericLoginSuccess" view="casLoginGenericSuccessView">
            <transition on="userManagement" to="userManagementHome" />
    </view-state>
```

default_views.properties

```
userManagementHome.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView 
userManagementHome.url=/WEB-INF/view/jsp/default/ui/userManagementHome.jsp
```

casGenericSuccessView.jsp

```
<jsp:directive.include file="includes/top.jsp" />
                <div id="msg" class="success">

<spring:message code="screen.success.header" />
                        <p><spring:message code="screen.success.success" /></p>
                        <p><spring:message code="screen.success.security" /></p>

                        <a href="login?_flowExecutionKey=${flowExecutionKey}&_eventId=userManagement">User   Management

                </div>
<jsp:directive.include file="includes/bottom.jsp" />
```

Also I tried changing href to login?&_eventId=userManagement

I have my userManagementHome.jsp at same place where casGenericSuccess.jsp is present.

can someone please help me out navigate to my page.

Right now it is not navigating and displays the same casGenericSuccess.jsp page on click of user management link.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `execution` instead of `_flowExecutionKey`